# Overlay DIV on Google Maps

Tags: css, google-maps

I am trying to position a div as an overlay on top of a Google Map.  I can't seem to keep it contained within the Google Maps div though.

```
#wrapperMap {
   position: relative;

}

#over {

background: #000000;
position: absolute; 
top: 120px; 
left: 10px; 
z-index: 99;
width: 20%;
height: 380px;
opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
color: #FFFFFF;
}


<div id="wrapperMap">

                <div id="map-canvas2" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border: 16px solid #e2e1e0;"></div>
                </div>


                <div id="over">

                        <br />

                        <div align="center">
                        <ul class="no_bullet">
                            <li class="school">SCHOOLS</li>
                            <li class="res">RESTAURANTS</li>
                            <li class="rec">RECREATION</li>
                            <li class="shop">SHOPPING</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

You can also see what is currently happening here, under "Current Projects -> Amenities" tab.

Comment: on you're website, the #over id is outside #wrapperMap id, double check their order its different from what you posted here

Comment: suggest changing absolute to fixed and adding a few pixels to the top/left

Comment: @ Crispy-George - I'm not seeing the #over div outside of #wrapperMap on the site code.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen - I thought position: fixed was always relative to the browser window.  How do I get it so it's relative to the #map-canvas2 div?

Comment: @user1110562 I may be overstretching on this issue, look closer after #map-cavas2, you have a extra </div> so the #over id will be rendered outside: http://s13.postimg.org/bq6bsdifr/via_source.jpg

Comment: I just noticed that extra DIV as well.  Removed it, but still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if you manage to get both the `#over` and `#map-canvas2` inside a separate wrapper, you can pull it off pretty easy like so:

- this wrapper that holds both these ids, set it to relative positioned, so that any absolute positioned children, will be bound to this parent;
- the overlay thingy, `#over`, set it to `position: absolute`, and if you want it to stretch to its parent height, then either use 100% height, or use top and bottom props.(dont forget to take into account any borders,margins etc.)
- and that should do it.

Check out the **[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/5pLu3084/)** and hopefully this will help you out.

Comment: This did the trick.  Now I can just adjust my font sizes within the overlay using @media selectors.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1110562 no problem-o, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#over {
background: #000000;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;
width: 20%;
height: 370px;
opacity: 0.9;
filter: alpha(opacity=90);
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
top: 15px;
margin-left: 16px;
}
```

After some inspecting element. I guess this is the possible solution i see. Try this code above. And put #wrapper on it. Like on the original html code you have before.

Comment: This places it at the top of the map div, which is not what I want to achieve.  I need the overlay to stay on the left side of the map div, and always be as high as the div..  with it extending to the right about 20% of the div width.

Comment: Yes because first of your sentence  is  "I am trying to position a div as an overlay on top of a Google Map." Maybe i misunderstand that.

Comment: Ah sorry... yes i mean overlayed on top of the div.  My initial code has it to the left and setup height wise, so that's how I need it, just always contained in the map div.

Comment: Yes that is it exactly.

Comment: If that's the case then you need to put the <div id="over"> inside the  
<div id="map-canvas2" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border: 16px solid #e2e1e0;"></div> then remove the top and left element on the css under #over on the css

Comment: <div id="map-canvas2" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; border: 16px solid #e2e1e0;">


                <div id="over">

                        <br />

                        <div align="center">
                        <ul class="no_bullet">
                            <li class="school">SCHOOLS</li>
                            <li class="res">RESTAURANTS</li>
                            <li class="rec">RECREATION</li>
                            <li class="shop">SHOPPING</li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

                </div>
</div>

try putting that way

Comment: @mimicode you'd be better off updating/editing your answer to the new stats, instead of pouring in comments a bunch of divs

Comment: I had already tried the #over div inside #map-canvas2, but it didn't appear at all.  I just put it back inside there so you could see how it's rendering.

Comment: Does it have something to do with calling the initalize2() function when clicking the "Amenities" tab, in order to call all the Google maps code at that point?  If I don't do it that way then the map doesn't render at all.

Comment: @user1110562 leave it inside, now I'm no seeing it; must have been removed or something when you click on AMENITIES it gets removed

Comment: @user1110562 don't place it inside #map-canvas2 it will get remove, set outside of it

Comment: I've set it back outside the @map-canvas2 div.  It's showing, but not in the right position.